# Add more text after using a filter in ng-bind in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind, angular-filters

So I want to put a variable through a filter inthe ng-bind directive

```
ng-bind="input | filter"
```

but I want to insert more text

```
ng-bind="input | filter + 'more' "
```

but this isn't working. Is there a way to add more text in ng-bind, like you could if you were simply using `{{}}`:

```
{{input | filter}} more
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Instead of interpolating(using `{{}}`) something in the `ng-bind` directive you can simply enclose the filtered value with a parenthesis and append your text.

```
<h1 ng-bind="(input | filter) + ' more stuff'"></h1>
```

furthermore, if the text you want to add is not in any way dynamic then I suggest you append another element to bind the filtered value and then add the text after that element.

e.g.

```
<h1><span ng-bind="(input | filter)"></span> more stuff</h1>
```

This saves you one concatenation process.

**[Example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UNEwVBUL9zwAraiUYIBh?p=preview)**

Comment: Oh, I didn't think to do that, haha. This is a better method than mine.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
<h1 ng-bind="'{{input | filter}}' + ' more stuff'"></h1>
```

Here's an example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/rEva7FTPFtr3im7RUlQk?p=preview

Comment: There's a caveat in this: it doesn't update when the `input` value changes. It's essentially becomes static after the first interpolation.