# AngularJS append text to ng-bind with filter

Tags: angularjs, filter, angular-filters, ng-bind

I have this code (output=1,000):

```
<span ng-bind"item.num | number : 0"></span>
```

But i want something like 1,000 km. Any way to do this without create a new span.

Something like this isn't working:

```
<span ng-bind"item.num + ' km' | number : 0"></span>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add more text after using a filter in ng-bind in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463473/add-more-text-after-using-a-filter-in-ng-bind-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<span ng-bind="(input | filter) + 'km'"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for this is :

```
<span ng-bind="(item.num | number : 0) + ' km' "></span>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/DPSph1yjyftEATWX6wsH?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

As a more generic solution, specify a custom filter [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ea7u3nr/):

```
.filter('formatNumber', function () {
    return function (input) {
        return input + 'km';
    }
});
```

And:

```
<span ng-bind="item.num | formatNumber"></span>
```

Comment: it could be done on HTML would be more better using `number` filter itself like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31923315/2435473

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using parenthesis.

```
<span ng-bind"(item.num | number : 0) + 'km' "></span>
```

If the unit is always km and is not dynamic, you can just put it in the regular text.

```
<div><p><span ng-bind"item.num | number : 0"></span>km</p></div>
```